# const amount = ethers.utils.parseEther("1");

Tags: testing, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, ethers.js

Is
`const amount = ethers.utils.parseEther("1");`
deprecated ?

this line of code is throwing an error while testing solidity smart contract.

Error = TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parseEther')

`const amount = ethers.parseEther("1");`
this is not throwing any error.

Comment: If you're using hardhat, you might need to import ethers by importing "hre". But without any more details, or code, we cannot really help you.

Answer (score 1):

`ethers.parseEther()` is available in Ethers v6 ([docs](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/utils/#parseEther)), while `ethers.utils.parseEther()` is the syntax from Ethers v5 ([docs](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/display-logic/#utils-parseEther)).

As *Martijn* mentioned in the comment, you need to use the expected syntax for the version that you're currently using.